# PowerShell Count Object's Property's Value Occurrence

Tags: powershell

I have employee details in employee.csv, which I have compiled each row in PS objects.

Now there will be `-NotePropertyName "EmployeeTotal_LeaveCount"` and the -`-NotePropertyValue` should be the total occurrence of `"YES"` in the final object-

**Single PSObject**

```
@{EmployeeID=MACL22656; EmployeeRole=Accountant; EmployeeDepartment=Accounts; EmployeeLeave_Monday=YES; EmployeeLeave_Tuesday=YES; EmployeeLeave_Thursday=YES}
```

**Expected Final Object:**

```
@{EmployeeID=MACL22656; EmployeeRole=Accountant; EmployeeDepartment=Accounts; EmployeeLeave_Monday=YES; EmployeeLeave_Tuesday=YES; EmployeeLeave_Thursday=YES; EmployeeTotal_LeaveCount=3}
```

So far I tried

```
$employee|Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EmployeeTotal_LeaveCount" -NotePropertyValue ($employee|Select-String -CaseSensitive -Pattern 'YES' | Measure-Object).count
```

But it returns - 1 instead of 3 [as 'YES' occurred 3 times in Object]

Please help to achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over properties whose name start with `EmployeeLeave_` and it's value is `YES`:

```
$Employee=[PSCustomObject]@{EmployeeID="MACL22656"
                            EmployeeRole="Accountant"
                            EmployeeDepartment="Accounts"
                            EmployeeLeave_Monday="YES"
                            EmployeeLeave_Tuesday="YES"
                            EmployeeLeave_Thursday="YES"
}

$Employee|Add-Member -NotePropertyName "EmployeeTotal_LeaveCount"  `
    -NotePropertyValue ($Employee.PSObject.Properties|
        where-Object {$_.Name -like "EmployeeLeave_*" -and $_.Value -eq "YES"}).count
$Employee
```

Sample output:

```
EmployeeID               : MACL22656
EmployeeRole             : Accountant
EmployeeDepartment       : Accounts
EmployeeLeave_Monday     : YES
EmployeeLeave_Tuesday    : YES
EmployeeLeave_Thursday   : YES
EmployeeTotal_LeaveCount : 3
```